# jquery draggable: how to read return values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

When using jquery draggable, if I wish to stop a drag as a result of a condition, I might use something like this

```
$('#selector').draggable({
    drag: function() {
        if (something)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

What I would like to do is then capture the result `true` or `false` and then execute some more code based on that. How can I "listen" to the drag, or "capture" this result? To what is this value being "returned" to?

Thanks!

Comment: It's just being returned to the event handler, you can't really catch it. If you want to do more, add functions to the condition that does stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use draggable events like this :

```
var globalFlag;
$( "#selector" ).draggable({
    drag: function() {
        console.log('drag event');
        if (something)
        {
            globalFlag = true;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            globalFlag = false;
            return false;
        }        
    },
    start: function() {
        console.log('drag start' + globalFlag);
    },
    stop: function() {
        console.log('drag stop' + globalFlag);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've updated the code including some dummy example. To be honest right now after reading your question again, I'm not exactly sure what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: so the value is preserved, but how would I proceed to do something with that value directly after the drag function has completed?

Comment: i have a draggable, if you drag it near a certain boundary, which is moving, i want the draggable to stop moving, but i don't want the drag event to stop, so i want to trigger a `mousedown()` event after returning false.

Comment: when you have a `containment` set, and it prevents you from dragging outside of the container, but does not actually stop the drag, I want to be able to trigger that behavior without using a container.

Comment: You have that explained on jQuery page : http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement - It's about movement constraint..

Comment: My issue was that, I did not want the user to drag it somewhere, but that place was dynamic so using `containment` was not enough for me. My solution was to let them drag it somewhere "bad", and then on the `stop` event, put it back to where it was before they started dragging. I can do that by storing the xy coordinates in the `start` event.

Comment: There are already some questions that could give you some clue on how to do that .. like dynamic containment -> [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103368/jquery-ui-draggable-update-containment-on-drag-event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103368/jquery-ui-draggable-update-containment-on-drag-event)